# wifi keeps disconnecting

Tags: wireless, disconnect

I have a dell vostro 2520. When I try to download huge files or when i just watch youtube videos wifi disconnects. I had the same problem on preinstalled windows 8 too. I thought if i install an Ubuntu 14.04 it will solve it, so i erased the windows and installed Ubuntu but the problem still exists.

this is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)


00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM75 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)

    this is the wifi section from the output of lshw command:

    *-network
    description: Wireless interface
    product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
    vendor: Broadcom Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
    logical name: wlan0
    version: 01
    serial: 9c:2a:70:bd:d9:fb
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=XXX.XXX.X.X latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
    resources: irq:19 memory:f7c00000-f7c07fff
```

Comment: Might be defective wifi card. I had realtek rtl8191, internal wifi card. While watching videos, any of them, sound would stutter (no such problem with previous card). When I got usb dongle with same chipset, it worked like charm, i even get connection in brick building on my college campus. Look it up on amazon !

Comment: you can repeat those actions that lead to wifi break and then run in terminal `cat /var/log/syslog | tail -10` and paste to e.g. http://pastebin.com/ and post a link here.

Comment: OP says "fixed by `sudo service network-manager restart`"

Comment: @Zanna It is not a solution.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is too vague for the various possible causes of random disconnection and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

could be many reasons and solutions,
can you go wired?
if its a personal home router, then go admin and configure the settings,
try connecting to the ip adress manually to secure the server from auto renewing. GL!